# ¿llenar textbox a travez de una consulta sql?

Tags: vb.net

No se como hacer lo siguiente:

Quiero llenar los TextBox de mi Formulario a partir del resultado de un consulta en sql.
Mi codigo de la consulta en visual es el siguiente:

```
  Public Function Busqueda() As String
    Dim con As String
    con = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=LabInventarioN3;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = con
    Dim query As New SqlCommand("select i.ID,i.Proyecto,i.Tipo, i.Cantidad,i.Ubicacion,i.Descripcion,i.Modelo,i.[Numero de Parte],
                                     i.NumeroSerie,i.Status,i.Comentarios from InventarioLab i where i.ID like '" & txtBuscarID.Text & "'", cnn)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlDataReader
    cmd = query.ExecuteReader()
    Dim res As String = Nothing
    If cmd.Read() Then res = cmd(0)
    cmd.Close()
    cnn.Close()
    Return res
End Function
```

El codigo del Boton es el siguiente:

```
   Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click

    txtID.Text = Busqueda()
    btnActualizar.Show()
    btnGuardar.Hide()

End Sub
```

El codigo funciona correctamente. Solo quiero que se llenen los TextBox con los datos obtenidos en su campo correspondiente

Mi formulario es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta se hace al dar click en el Boton Buscar.

Gracias.

Comment: visual studio es la ide donde estas programando (nada que ver con tu problema).. tampoco sql es tu problema.. estas usando executenonquery, que no devuelve un resultado. Investiga sobre ExecuteReader y ahi va a devolver un DataReader que podes recorrer y obtener los datos https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: ya lo realize @gbianchi. ahora el detalle es como recorro los datos para llenar los texbox?

Comment: en la misma pagina de ayuda habia un ejemplo... lo probaste?

Comment: @gbianchi no. ese ExecuteReader ya lo tenia en otro proyecto. y solo lo adapte a este  nuevo. y en donde estoy programando es en Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
 Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
    Try

        Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=LabInventarioN3;User ID=f5;Password=f5report")
            cnn.Open()
            Dim query As String = "select i.ID,i.Proyecto,i.Tipo, i.Cantidad,i.Ubicacion,i.Descripcion,i.Modelo,i.[Numero de Parte] NumeroParte,
                                     i.NumeroSerie,i.Status,i.Comentarios from InventarioLab i where i.ID like '" & txtBuscarID.Text & "'"
            Dim DataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn)
            DataSet = New DataSet

            DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "i")
            txtID.DataBindings.Clear()
            txtID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.ID"))
            TXTProyecto.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTProyecto.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Proyecto"))
            TXTTipo.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTTipo.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Tipo"))
            TXTCantidad.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTCantidad.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Cantidad"))
            TXTUbicacion.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTUbicacion.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Ubicacion"))
            TXTDescripcion.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTDescripcion.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Descripcion"))
            TXTModelo.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTModelo.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Modelo"))
            TXTNP.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTNP.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.NumeroParte"))
            TXTNumeroSerie.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTNumeroSerie.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.NumeroSerie"))
            TXTStatus.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTStatus.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Status"))
            TXTComentarios.DataBindings.Clear()
            TXTComentarios.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DataSet, "i.Comentarios"))

        End Using
        btnActualizar.Show()
        btnEliminar.Show()
        btnGuardar.Hide()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " + ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Saludos...